# Non-Google User Authentication on Google Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building an API-driven iOS app on Google App Engine. I'm a bit puzzled as to how we have a "login" system and secure API endpoints. We're using the Java SDK.

We don't want to require our users to have a Google account, so we're using Stormpath on the back-end, which is largely irrelevant. It just requires a username:password.

What's the best way to go about this? Do I override a custom UserService interface? Do something with sessions?

I've tried searching for this on google and SO, but so far no one's given a concrete answer for this on the Java side of things, although people in Python seem to have success with webapp2?

Comment: FYI: ultimately solved this by using Auth0

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for this.